# What is the correct way to add tab stops using the google docs API

Tags: python-3.x, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I tried the following:

```
{'updateParagraphStyle': {
    'paragraphStyle': {
        'namedStyleType': "NORMAL_TEXT",
        'alignment': "END",
        'direction': "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
        'borderBottom': {
            'width': {'magnitude': 1.5, 'unit': "PT"},
            'padding': {'magnitude': 1, 'unit': "PT"},
            'dashStyle': "SOLID"
        },
        'tabStops': [
            {
                'offset': {
                    'magnitude': 431.84999999999997,
                    'unit': 'PT'
                },
                'alignment': 'END'
            }
        ],
    },
    'range': {'startIndex': 1, 'endIndex': 10},
    'fields': "tabStops,namedStyleType,alignment,direction,borderBottom"
}}
```

but it complains about `tabStops`:

```
E googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting
https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1RGkXvV8M321KiuDjbMCQwzc52iEEPRxpFqttKmXnWwQ:batchUpdate?alt=json
returned "Invalid requests[2].updateParagraphStyle: Unallowed field: tabStops". Details: "Invalid
requests[2].updateParagraphStyle: Unallowed field: tabStops">
```

The other fields work fine.. i.e namedStyleType,alignment,direction,borderBottom

Comment: When I saw [the official document of ParagraphStyle](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#paragraphstyle), it seems that the document says `This property is read-only.` for `tabStops[]`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

Comment: Thanks - that would explain why.. now I need to know how to create/add tab stops.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that Document service cannot also set the tab stops. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document) I deeply apologize for this. So for example, how about adding a star to this future request? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765521

Comment: @Tanaike - thanks for letting me know, and yes - I have starred the issue. Also - is there a hack that you can suggest? Modify the raw json somehow?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, Google Document service and Google Docs API cannot achieve your goal. So I cannot propose the workaround for achieving your goal now. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.